# How to find temporary corporation with 0% tax?

Tags: eve-online

I play Eve Online since few days ago and I like it. What I don't like is my default corporation eating 11% of my earnings. Can you suggest me some corporation with 0% tax? I found some in the game, but they seem to be inactive and no one is processing my application.

Comment: Don't look for corporations with 0% tax, look for corporations that are doing what you want to do. A 0% tax does nothing for you; a corporation full of experienced players will help you understand the game, provide valuable fitting advice and get you experience of your own. Try out a couple of different activities, then look for a corporation that focuses on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't worry too much about taxes.

At first, it might look like a lot of money drained, but overall it doesn't apply to everything you earn (plus it only applies to sums being bigger than 100k isk).

Instead, you should try to find a corporation that fits your play style. If you're lucky, the corporation taxes will be lower as well (so it's a win-win) or you might get something back for your taxes (help, free modules, cheaper production stuff, etc.).

If you still think you really have to have mininmal taxes, just create your own corporation (there's a separated line of skills where you'll only need a rather minimalistic set to setup a basic corporation).

Comment: I'd add that being in a player-owned corporation or creating one yourself carries the additinoal risk of being war-decced. That's fine if you're in a corporation that can handle that, but it is a factor to consider when leaving the NPC corp.